# How to write a custom evaluation metric in python for xgboost?

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost, objective-function

I would like to add the kappa evaluation metric to use in xgboost in Python. I am having trouble understanding how to connect a Python function with xgboost.

According to the xgboost documentation, a "User can add multiple evaluation metrics, for python user, remember to pass the metrics in as list of parameters pairs instead of map, so that latter ‘eval_metric’ won’t override previous one"

This has been raised in [xgboost's github page](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1152) for R but not for Python.

For example if the kappa function is:

```
def kappa(preds, y):
    # perform kappa calculation
    return score
```

How do I go about implementing it with xgboost?
Specifing `'kappa'` as a string in the `eval_metric` parameter
results in `XGBoostError: unknown evaluation metric type: kappa`.

Likewise specifying the kappa method object results in `XGBoostError: unknown evaluation metric type: <function kappa at 0x7fbef4b03488>`.

How can a custom evaluation metric be used in xgboost in python?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change your method to:

```
def kappa(preds, y):
    # perform kappa calculation
    return 'kappa', score
```

And use it with `feval` argument:

```
bst = xgb.train(params, dtrain, num_rounds, watchlist, feval=kappa, maximize=False)
```

When writing custom evaluation metrics remember about setting `maximize` argument. Setting it to true means that the algorithm is getting better with bigger score of the evaluation metric.